# Map from Integers to natural numbers with property.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

> I am trying to construct a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(-1,0,1) = (1,1,1)$ and the set satisfies:
>
> (a) $S = \{k \in \mathbb{Z} : f(k,k+1,k+2) = (1,1,1) \}$ is infinite and such that $\forall m \in \mathbb{N} , \exists t \in \mathbb{Z} : \{t+1, \dots, t+m\} \cap S = \emptyset$ (unbounded gaps).
>
> (b) the property that for any finite sequence of natural numbers $(a_{1} , \dots , a_{t})$, $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z} : f(m+1,m+2, \dots , m+t) = (a_{1} , \dots , a_{t})$.
>
> In summary, I want the repetitions of $(1,1,1)$ to not occur regularly (but infinitely, part (b) guarantees the infinite part of (a)) and $f$ should be able to reproduce any finite sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: You appear to be misusing notation. When you write $f(-1,0,1)=(1,1,1)$, you’re saying that the ordered triple $\langle -1,0,1\rangle$ is in the domain of $f$, and the ordered triple $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ is in the range of $f$. Thus, $f$ might be a function from $\Bbb Z^3$ to $\Bbb N^3$, but it can’t be a function from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb N$. From the rest of the question I suspect that what you meant is that $\langle f(-1),f(0),f(1)\rangle=\langle 1,1,1\rangle$; is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for the notation, I mean to say $f(-1) = f(0) = f(1) = 1$. Essentially, I am trying to think of mappings of strings.

Comment: Well, the number of finie sequence of natural numbers is countable so you can have a bijection $j:\mathbb N\to $ such sequences.  so let the function be $1,1,1,j(0),1,1,1,f(1),1,1,1,  f(2), $ and so on that there are finite sequences with "1,1,1" guaretees a).

Comment: @fleablood I think this is it. Since the finite sequences have length which goes to infinity, part (a) is satisfied. My question is: is the string $\dots j(-1) ,1 ,1 ,1 , j(0) , 1,1,1, j(1) , \dots$ countable, does it have countably many digits?

Comment: Well, the digits are listed one after another so ... yes.  Although you can have sequences of any length *none* of them are actually infinite so that is okay.  The issue is whether $j$ really *is* a bijection and whether this satisfies a) and b).  I admit I didn't put my nose to the grindstone but I'm pretty sure that all are true.... And what *is* $j$.  But I'm pretty sure the number of finite sequence *is* infinitely countable so a $j$ *does* exist.

Comment: @user100101212 Then edit your question so it says what you are intending to say instead of the incoherence you posted.